# Spring cloud AWS: send to SQS URL rather than to Queue Name

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I'm trying to use [spring-cloud-aws](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/) to send messages to Amazon SQS.

Is there any way to, send messages to a URL, instead of to a queue name?

I.e., instead of:

```
queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, message);
```

I'd like to do

```
queueMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_URL, message);
```

You can do this in the AmazonSQSClient by doing

```
sqsClient.sendMessage(QUEUE_URL, message)
```

Likewise for the @MessageMapping annotation, I'd like to do

```
@MessageMapping(QUEUE_URL)
```

instead of

```
@MessageMapping(QUEUE_NAME)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -3):

Yes! entirely possible.

example:

```
@SqsListener (MY_QUEUE_NAME)
```